# How to skip quotes from code igniter active record update in order to use if condition in update?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, quotes, skip

I am writing query like this :-

```
$data = array(
    'company_billing' => "if (company_billing  = $userId, (NULL), $userId)",
    'company_admin' => "if (company_admin  = $userId, (NULL), $userId)",
);

$this->db->where('id', $organizationId);
$this->db->update('organization', $data);
```

I was expecting something like :-

```
UPDATE `organization` SET `organization`.`company_billing` = if (company_billing = 2, (NULL), 2), `organization`.`company_admin` = if (company_admin = 2, (NULL), 2) WHERE `id` = 1
```

But I am getting :-

```
UPDATE `organization` SET `organization`.`company_billing` = 'if (company_billing = 2, (NULL), 2)', `organization`.`company_admin` = 'if (company_admin = 2, (NULL), 2)' WHERE `id` = 1
```

I want to skip those quotes around if condition block.

Is there any way to achieve this or I will have to write native query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::update` and `::insert` function values are escaped automatically producing safer queries.

```
$this->db->set('company_billing' , "if (company_billing  = $userId, (NULL), $userId)", false);
$this->db->set('company_admin', "if (company_admin  = $userId, (NULL), $userId)", false);
$this->db->where('id', $organizationId);
$this->db->update('organization');
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response.
Ya, I am aware of this. Thats why I posted the question sseeking the answer.

Comment: just wanted to say, LOL @JatinDhoot first comment